Virtual path maps to another application
I'm am getting the following error when I run my VS WCF app.

The virtual path '/MyApp/MyService.svc' maps to another application,
which is not allowed.
[ArgumentException: The virtual path '/MyApp/MyService.svc' maps to
another application, which is not allowed.]
System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath,
Boolean permitPathsOutsideApp) +247
System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData() +31
System.Web.HttpContext.GetConfigurationPathData() +27
System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(HttpContext context)
+48    System.Web.Configuration.CustomErrorsSection.GetSettings(HttpContext
context, Boolean canThrow) +42
System.Web.HttpResponse.ReportRuntimeError(Exception e, Boolean
canThrow, Boolean localExecute) +103
System.Web.HttpContext.ReportRuntimeErrorIfExists(RequestNotificationStatus&
status) +485

The app was working before, I think I upgraded VS 2019 to '16.11.35' and then this issue started to occur but I'm not sure. I have IIS 10 Express installed. I am at a lost why this is happening now. Can anyone offer insights or solution to this issue?
I am aware of the post The virtual path [path] maps to another application but it does not answer the question.
Thank you!

You can try: ~/MyApp/MyService.svc.
If it still doesn't work, please check Solution->Properties->Web ->Virtual Path.
